# jQuery src does not update on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that loads demo video using jVideo.js and it plays perfectly.

```
<div id="divVideo">
    <video id="videoId" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
    controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" 
    data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 4, 8] }' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js"> To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider 
            upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
        </p>
    </video>
</div>
```

I now add a mouse click event that will switch out the demo video and play another video.

The mouse click event is here:

```
<script>
 function canvasClick() {
   var videoFile = 'data/video1/20160705_081435_E.mp4';
   $('#divVideo video source').attr('src',videoFile );
   $("#divVideo video")[0].load();
 };
</script>
```

This video is switched in and plays perfectly as well, however if I replace the src file from

```
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

to something local, for example

```
<source src="Videos/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

which is the same file, this also plays perfectly, but now the mouse click event does not work.

The binding code is:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    canvasClick();
```

The question is, is there anything wrong with my mouse click event or the structure of my html?

Comment: Where is binding ? Add listener adding code.

Comment: I think Your binding is wrong because code is looking ok, I used You code and add onclick on video and code is working - https://plnkr.co/edit/g8ai5NKahoeNRrlwrnDV?p=preview.

Comment: I don't think the binding can be wrong because the event fires and it works when the url is in place of the local video file

Comment: Okay, just added to the main question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a work around if anyone needs it.   Remove the `<source>` tags.  The code now looks like:

```
<div id="divVideo">
            <video id="videoId" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
            controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" 
            data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 4, 8] }' 
            src="videos/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js"> To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider 
                upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
            </p>
        </video>
    </div>
```

and the jQuery like:

```
<script>
 function canvasClick() {
   var videoFile = 'data/video1/20160705_081435_E.mp4';
   $('#divVideo video').attr('src',videoFile );
   $('#divVideo video')[0].load();
};
```

Why it works now - heaven knows!